# check google spreadsheet from a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets

how do i validate data against a google spreadsheet from a html page using jquery or javascript so for example a user enters a value and clicks the button then the value of the input field is checked for in the spreadsheet if it exists return true

```
<input type="text" id="user"/>
<button id="get_data">validate</button>

<script>
$("#get_data").click(function(){
    var x = $("#user").text();
    spreadsheet_url = ""
    if(check_if_x_is_in_google_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_url, x)){
        alert("ok")
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the API `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get`
passing input parameters:

- spreadsheetId = The ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from. In your case is the last part of your *spreadsheet_url* parameter (e.g. 1N55k_S_zHAY94twYGnot37q7tjrU1vET_iAn6sYxy20 on https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N55k_S_zHAY94twYGnot37q7tjrU1vET_iAn6sYxy20  )
- range = The A1 notation of the values to retrieve.

as described on method
[gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) .

Before call the api you have to initialize the client library with apiKey and clientId as documented on this [example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js).

So your `check_if_x_is_in_google_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_url, x)` function may be

```
  function check_if_x_is_in_google_spreadsheet(spreadsheetId, x) {
    gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
      range: 'Class Data!A:E',
    }).then(function(response) {
      var range = response.result;
      if (range.values.length > 0) {

        for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
          var row = range.values[i];
          // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
          if (row[0] == x) { //0 is A column
           alert('got it') // some staff
           return true;
          }
        }
      } else {
        alert('No data found!!');
      }
    }, function(response) {
      alert('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
    });
    return false;
  }
```